# Events in Chainlink Keepers checkUpkeep() not emited

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I created a bare bone Chainlink keeper for testing purpose. In checkUpkeep, I set upkeepNeeded to true and emit an event. In performUpkeep, I increment a counter and emit another event. Surprisingly, only the event in performUpkeep is emitted. Anyone knows why the event in checkUpkeep is not emitted?

**Link to contract deployed on kovan:**
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xE5c13FEe7F4DDBB19f0941b8616f8B9D5EB77dB5#events

**Link to keeper:**
https://keepers.chain.link/kovan/2738

**Contract code:**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData);
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external;
}

contract Huma is KeeperCompatibleInterface {

    event UpkeepChecked(uint256 timestamp);
    event UpkeepPerformed( uint counter );
    uint public counter;

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {       
        upkeepNeeded = true;
        performData = checkData;
        emit UpkeepChecked(block.timestamp);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
        counter++;
        emit UpkeepPerformed(counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink keepers only simulate calling `checkUpkeep`.

[Per the docs.](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/#checkupkeep-function)

> Because checkUpkeep is only ever performed off-chain in simulation, for most cases it is best to treat this as a view function and not modify any state. This might not always be possible if you want to use more advanced Solidity features like DelegateCall. It is a best practice to import the KeeperCompatible.sol contract and use the cannotExecute modifier to ensure that the method can be used only for simulation purposes.